# Replace n-th item in list of lists

Tags: haskell

I work on simple function to replace n-th item in list of lists by list of lists.

Input: `replaceNth 2 [["0","1"],["8","8"]] [["2","3"],["1","2"],["3","4"],["9","12"]]`

Expected output: `[["2","3"],["1","2"],["0","1"],["8","8"],["9","12"]]`

Currently I got following code which doesn't work correctly.

```
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
    | n == 0 = newVal:[xs]
    | otherwise = [x]++replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
```

Could you help me to fix the function?

Comment: You should always start writing a function from its intended type. In that way, GHC will produce better error messages.

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. In your example, the 4-th sublist has been deleted (instead of the 2-th, as one could think), and the order of the sublists has been perturbed in a way I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you need to concatenate `newVal` with the rest of the list so it type-checks. You can also use pattern matching instead of guards.

```
replaceNth 0 newVal (x:xs) = newVal ++ xs 
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs) = x : replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
```

To complete this function, you need to provide a case for the empty list (if applies)